# Netty - How to implement the Fan-Out pattern

Tags: netty

is there any example that shows how to implement the fan-out pattern? basically in my Handler I want to send out multiple requests and then handle the result of those.

Comment: did you try using a Channel group : ChannelGroupFuture future = broadcast.writeAndFlush(message);
future.awaitUninterruptibly();

Comment: It would be useful if you gave some examples to how you want to use the result, at the moment, I have to google what exactly "fan-out pattern" means, and I'm assuming not everyone takes the effort to answer a question that requires googling before they what the question means

Answer (score 1):

For multiple targets I believe you can use [PromiseAggregator](https://netty.io/4.1/api/index.html?io/netty/util/concurrent/PromiseAggregator.html) and/or [PromiseCombiner](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/PromiseCombiner.html). If I understand your use case correctly, then these abstractions were designed to do just that: join multiple futures/promises and await for their aggregated result. Details may differ depending on your requirements, you may want to fail if at least one promise fails or you may be fine if at least one completes. Anyway, some examples may be found in the docs or here: [PromiseCombiner example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseCombiner).

```java
final PromiseCombiner combiner = new PromiseCombiner(eventExecutor);
combiner.add(makeAsyncCall1());
combiner.add(makeAsyncCall2());
final DefaultPromise<Void> promise = new DefaultPromise<>(eventExecutor);
promise.addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<? super Void>>() {
    @Override
    public void operationComplete(Future<? super Void> future) throws Exception {
        // handle
    }
});
combiner.finish(promise);
```

Comment: this works great if you have to perform an action after the async calls have finished. the finish() promise is called once all of the async calls have terminated. but the combiner result is a void. so the results must be stored somewhere outside, i guess. do you know if there is already something like this that provide the list of results in the finish() listener? anyway even storing the result outside and get them on the finish listener doesn't look that bad. thanks!

Comment: @th30z hm, it seems that API was designed to only support Void i.e. for signaling. I guess it's fine to aggregate the results in a shared collection. Just be aware of possible race issues.